# codeigniter ajax function shows 404 (not found) on live server but work properly on localhost

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, codeigniter

This is working perfect for me and my team locally, but once we pull it to the live server and try it, it gives me a 404 error.

HTML Code :

```
<form method="post" id="filter_form" action="<?=base_url('admin/product/product_stock')?>;">;
    <select data-placeholder="Please Select Root Category...." class="span12 required" name="root_category_id" id="root_category_id">
        <option value="">Please Select Root Category....</option>
        <option value="a">Root Category A</option>
        <option value="b">Root Category B</option>
        <option value="c">Root Category C</option>
    </select>
    <select data-placeholder="Please Select Category...." class="span12 required" name="category_id" id="category_id">
        <option value="">Please Select Category....</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Ajax Call :

```
$('#root_category_id').live('change', function(evt, params) {
    var opt = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?=base_url()?>admin/product/get_category_ajax",
        data:"root_category_id="+opt,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#category_id").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller function being called :

```
function get_category_ajax() {
    $root_category_id = $this->input->post("root_category_id");
    $data["get_categories_records"] = $this->product_model->getCategoryListbyAjax($root_category_id);
    $this->load->view("admin/RequiredCategoryByAjax",$data);
}
```

HTACCESS :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Tried in config.php too but didn't worked.

```
    $config['index_page'] = ''
```

Comment: did you change the base_url() in your production config?

Comment: @Vickel The base_url in config file is properly defined and it is working everywhere else...

Comment: ^ how does it look like?

Comment: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#site_url